# Change connString dynamically

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently working on an `ASP.NET` `MVC` project with `Entity Framework`. The solution includes the `ASP.NET` `MVC` application and a `DataProvider` project. The project only includes an `EF` model, as I have a partner who shares a database with me.

The problem is in that, that we don't actually share the same database. What I mean is that the actual server of the database is not the same. We have the same tables. But the connection string has to be changed every single time we pull from our `git` repository. The string changes in the `web.config` file of the `ASP.NET` `MVC` project and in the `app.config` file of the `EF` library.

My question is - if there is a way for our system to detect which `PC` it is running on and modify the connection string dynamically? Now I do it manually.

```
<!--PC NICO CEI-->

<!--
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbShubertEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelDbShubert.csdl|res://*/ModelDbShubert.ssdl|res://*/ModelDbShubert.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=E04\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbShubert;user id=gereisma17;password=12321;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
-->

<!--PC NICO Laptop-->

<!--
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbShubertEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelDbShubert.csdl|res://*/ModelDbShubert.ssdl|res://*/ModelDbShubert.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-I62BLOC;initial catalog=dbShubert;user id=user;password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
-->
```

This is what I do now. I am commenting the connection string. I want to automate the whole thing.

Comment: Please shorten your sentences. That more people can help you with your question. Also I didn't get where is the question.

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Why not simply add the web.config or app.config to .gitignore file

Comment: You could have an **environment variable** like `PCName` or something that is defined on a **per machine** basis, that you could then read out and decide which connection string to use for your current environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using aspnet core there is a way to configure environment variable as override for the app settings
this way you'll have a "default" appsettings.json that contains all the common settings, then on the different machine you can configure environmnet variables that replaces (override) the connection string in different way for each machine

i suppose a similar approach is possible for aspnet for the full framework as well

as your connection string have already a quite specific name "dbShubertEntities" it sould be quite effective to override and you should not risk to have connection string collisions in case you work on different projects.

as reference see https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-configuration-deep-dive the part where it uses .AddEnvironmentVariables()

Answer (score 2):

You could overload the DbContext's constructor with the dynamic connection string

```
public class MasterDal : DbContext
    {
        public MasterDal(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {

        }
       // DbSet &  OnModelCreating etc 
    }
```

& then invoke dal in Controller as required

```
if (logicToGetPc.equal("CEI"))
 { 
    MasterDal dal = new MasterDal("dbShubertEntitiesCEI");
   // do  mumbai related whatever 
 }
 else if (logicToGetPc.equal("Laptop"))
 {
     MasterDal dal = new MasterDal("dbShubertEntitiesCEILaptop");
 }
```

Comment: What does logicToGetPc do? Does it check a enviroment variable?

Comment: it is a function which you need to define...& it shell get you whether "PC NICO Laptop-" or if it is the other one

Answer (score 1):

Store the connection string as an environment variable on each PC.

When creating the connection to the database, retrieve the connection string using [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

(at time of writing, there's no code)

This is what appsettings.json, (or it's counterparts), was made for.

As i perceive your predicament, (you need more whitespace in your writing to make it easier to read), you are basically working in two different environments, (similar to dev versus test). A simple configuration change would be the simplest way.

As an aside:
Reading between the lines, it seems like you are hard-coding connection strings, and I have a two-word advice for you: STOP IT! (I used to do that, and It's a bad habit that can be hard to shake off)